# Subbing literal to Row() breaks INDIRECT()?

Tags: excel-formula, openoffice.org

My document is much like a book where each Sheet is like a page, in fact like a chapter.

At the beginning of the doc I have a page that's similar to a table of contents.  So beginning let's say at E10 I have

```
Topic:        Page: 

Apple         7

Banana        3

Cherry        2
```

Each topic refers to a sheet which has the exact same name, and each such page has its Page # stored in the Cell B2.  To support automatic self-numbering regardless of sheet reordering, in the above table I have formulae calculate the page #, so where it says "7", the formula is

```
=INDIRECT($E$10 & ".B2")
```

So $E$10 gives me "Apple", then I get "Apple.B2" which returns the 7.

But now for Banana, the formula is

```
=INDIRECT($E$11 & ".B2")
```

I have to change the 10 to an 11.  I want something like this, the same formula for every row:

```
=INDIRECT( "$E$" & ROW() & ".B2")
```

I've tried a billion things, but I just can't get it.  What's weird is that I can generate "Apple.B2" just fine, but when I pass it to INDIRECT() it breaks.  Thx.

Comment: change your formula to `=INDIRECT($E10 & ".B2")` and copy down.  The row is now relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually checking two different cells, so each one needs `INDIRECT`:

```
=INDIRECT( INDIRECT("$E$" & ROW()) & ".B2")
```